# Python crashes when trying to compile using cx_Freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm trying to compile my python scripts using cx_Freeze, here is my setup file:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import matplotlib
import os
base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\\Python35\\tcl\\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\\Python35\\tcl\\tk8.6'

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("HomeScreen.py", base=base, 
icon="icon.png")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "LeagueBoost",
    options = {"build_exe":{"packages": ["sqlite3","requests","time","sys","os","statistics","matplotlib","random","collections"],
                            "include_files": ["Assets", "LeagueBoost_v1.py","LBRun.py","graphSetup.py","profilepage.py","Assets_rc.py"]}},
    version = "1",
    executables = executables
    )
```

But when I give the cmd command `C:/python35/python.exe`, it gets to `copying C:\python35\python35.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\python35.dll` it pops up "python has stopped working"

Answer (score 3):

This is crazy
after hitting my head against the wall for the weird reason python crashes when I tried to build executable with cx_Freeze, 
what solved my problem is using `ico` format for icon file.

Your icon file should be `icon` type not `png`, may be because `png` is not supported by cx_Freeze.

In your `setup.py` change
`icon="icon.png"` to `icon="icon.ico"`,
please note the icon file must be in `ico` format, don't act smart and just change the extension.

If it still doesn't work you can give it a trial without writing this option at all `icon="icon.png"` and see if it works.

Comment: I believe it is Windows, not cx_Freeze, that supports only an `ico` file as application icon. On the Wikipedia [ICO (file format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)) page, one can read: `In Windows, all executables that display an icon to the user, on the desktop, in the Start Menu, or in Windows Explorer, must carry the icon in ICO format.` However, I'm not been able to find a corresponding statement in the an "official" Windows documentation.